# Yii2 doesn't upgrade yii\jui library to latest version. How to upgrade?

Tags: php, yii2

I tried to upgrade yii\jui library to latest version (jquery-ui 13.1) however it wasn't successful. In Yii2 it uses the outdated version which no longer has support.

Answer (score 0):

I just found a solution. Bower Asset doesn't support jquery-ui 13.1 so it's useless instead you can either use npm Asset by adding "npm-asset/jquery-ui": ">=1.13.0" to your config file or you can add the following code in your Asset Manager

```html
'bundles' => [
                'yii\jui\JuiAsset' => [
                    'sourcePath' => null,   // do not publish the bundle
                    'js' => [
                        '//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/jquery-ui.min.js',
                    ],
                    'css' => [
                        '//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css',
                    ],

                ],
            ]
```

Answer (score 0):

One alternative way to go is [forking](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/quickstart/fork-a-repo) the repositories on github of the projects that install the jquery-jui plugin.

```
https://github.com/components/jqueryui
https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-jui
```

Then, you should upgrade the versions of the js files from v1.12.1 to v1.13.x and replace the actual files.

To pulish things up, you should test that all the widgets and effects in both projects (js and php) work well with the new version.

Then you should modify your project's composer.json file to load your forked repos instead of the original ones.