# How to use the jquery-ui library 1.13 in Yii2?

Tags: jquery, npm, jquery-ui, yii2

I would like to use the latest [jquery-ui](https://jqueryui.com/download/) library in Yii2, that at present is the 1.13.2, but Yii2 uses the outdated 1.12.1 release, which has no longer support.

I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72173389/yii2-doesnt-upgrade-yii-jui-library-to-latest-version-how-to-upgrade), but I didn't understand where to add the line "npm-asset/jquery-ui": ">=1.13.0" to my config file, as suggested in the answer. I also realized that I don't have the "npm-asset" subfolder in my "vendor" folder and didn't understand how to download it.

Thanks

Comment: They probably meant your `composer.json` file. The subfolder will be created by composer when you run `composer update` after adding any `npm-asset` dependency.

Comment: Thanks, I added it and now I have the "npm-asset" folder in the "vendor" folder. Now how can I tell Yii2 to use the jquery-ui of the "npm-asset" folder instead of that of the "bower-asset" folder? I would not want to change any source file, like for example the $sourcePath value in the JuiAsset file.